# JSONUtility supports output a value of type json to a String variable? Unity

Tags: json, unity-game-engine

I have a json like this {"company":{"Name":"Example", "Code":300}}, how do i serialize this json inside a json key to my class? Im trying to receive some data from api.

```
[Serializable]
public class SLogin{
    public string company;
}
    
SLogin sLogin = JsonUtility.FromJson<SLogin>(www.downloadHandler.text);
```

This is a sample of a code I'm using, as you see i have a json object as a value of "company" key, this is a bit confusing, but i want it to be a string containing a json string.

Comment: Did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Well, see [Unity - JSON Serialization](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/JSONSerialization.html): Your class structure has to reflect the JSON data structure and would have to look like

```
[Serializable]
public class SLogin
{
    public Company company;
}

[Serializable]
public class Company
{
    public string Name;
    public int Code;
}
```

and then

```
var sLogin = JsonUtility.FromJson<SLogin>(www.downloadHandler.text);

Debug.Log($"Name = \"{sLogin.company.Name}\", Code = \"{sLogin.company.Code}\"");
```